# After setting up an Active Directory child domain, I cannot log in as any users of the child domain

Tags: active-directory, domain

I'm having some trouble setting up a Child Active Directory Domain.

I started by installing Windows Server 2012 R2 we will call `NICK1` and installed Active Directory Domain Services on this server as domain `nicholas.com`. I also configured this server as the DNS server.

Now I want to add a child domain `sub.nicholas.com`.

Here are the steps I performed to create the child domain.

- Install another copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 we will call `NICK2`. Configure this server to be a child domain of `NICK1`'s `nicholas.com` by doing the following:

  - Configure the Network Connection to use `NICK1`'s DNS server.

    - (View Network Connections -> Click on your Ethernet NIC -> Properties -> Double Click your IPv4 protocol in the list -> Click “Use the following DNS Server Address” and set it to the DNS server’s IP address.)
  - Join the `nicholas.com` domain: Go to “View your PC name” and click “Join a domain”

    - Type the fully qualified domain name of the root active directory domain and join it. Authenticate using the root domain’s admin username/password.
    - Restart when prompted.
    - When you log back in, use the administrator/password from the root domain controller.
  - Install the Active Directory services. (Go to Server Manager -> Add roles or features -> Next -> Next-> Next -> Choose Active Directory Domain Services -> Add features -> Next -> Next -> Next -> Install. Wait for the Active Directory Domain Services to install.)
  - Promote to a domain controller and configure as a sub domain:

    - Go to server manager and Click on the yellow flag
    - Promote this server to a domain controller.
    - Select Add domain to existing forest (The FQDN of the root domain should appear automatically in Parent domain name)
    - Enter the new child domain name `sub`
    - Enter login credentials for `administrator@nicholas.com`
    - The defaults for the rest. Install.

This process completes fine and I'm able to log in to the domain controller as the new `SUB\Administrator` user.

But when I create a new AD user in `sub.nicholas.com`, I cannot log in as that user.

I also cannot log in as any `sub.nicholas.com` users in any other services that work with `nicholas.com`. For example... `user@nicholas.com` is able to use sharepoint, but `otheruser@sub.nicholas.com` cannot.

Does anyone know what steps I'm missing to make the `sub.nicholas.com` domain usable? My main goal is to be able to use SharePoint as a `nicholas.com` user or a `sub.nicholas.com` user.

Comment: Windows Server 2013 is not a thing. Typo?

Comment: yep corrected. thanks. got it mixed up in my head with the sharepoint version i'm using.

Comment: It shouldn't make a huge difference, but you might also want to clarify whether you are referring to 2012 (the original) or 2012 R2.

Comment: done. i am using the R2

Comment: Do you have client computers joined to both domains? If so can you verify/clarify which logon attempts work and which don't between domain users and domain computers? E.g., user@nicholas.com can log on to both client computers but user@sub.nicholas.com can only log on to the computer joined to the sub domain or to neither one.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I didn't know you could join both domains from the client machine. That might be the step I'm missing.

Comment: I meant two separate computers, one joined to each domain. One computer cannot be joined to more than one domain, no.

Comment: Let me try to configure a computer joined to the sub domain and see if i can log in there. I'm guessing that will work. I also editted my question with my main intention - to be able to use SharePoint as a nicholas.com user or a sub.nicholas.com user. When done I will edit my question with the clarifications you requested.